# Trigger a JS/Jquery transition in background color when an anchor is present

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can one implement the type of background color changing that you see on stack overflow when you link directly to one of the answers via an `a` tag?

e.g.

- `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821321/what-does-the-utmscr-or-utmcct-values-mean-in-reference-to-the-http-cookie-serve/#1401813`

Note the `#1401813` on the end is the answer id.

Navigating there will trigger the background color of the container to glow for a second, and return.

I have the ids set up on my containers, and the links working fine, in that the page jumps down to the appropriate area, but I am not sure how to use either pure `js` or `jquery` to realize there is a anchor reference in the url, and transition the background color into, and out of, a glow color for that container.

Anyone have any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pure JS/CSS implementation. For the sake of using JSFiddle, I'm setting the `window.location.hash` manually, but you'd fetch it the exact same way.

```
window.location.hash = "foo";

function highlight() {
  let id = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  let node = document.getElementById(id);
  if (node) {
    node.classList.add('flash');
  }
}
highlight();
```

You're simply reading the hash and finding if an element on your page has that ID. The `substr` is to snip the # out of the hash. Then you add a class to that element that has a CSS animation. In this case, changing the background to red, then back to its original color.

```
.flash {
  animation-name: redflash;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes redflash {
  from {
    background-color: #FF0000;
  }
  to {
    background-color: inherit;
  }
}
```

Here's a fiddle that shows it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/904tsLah/11/

And here's a fiddle that includes an implementation of how you could use that idea to navigate around a page. https://jsfiddle.net/904tsLah/18/

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite easy.  Simply read in the hash value via `location.hash` (remove the pound symbol if needed).  Locate the related item via id, or class.  Then you can animate the background color (i did it with jQuery UI).  [You can also change color via CSS 3 pretty easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411306/transition-of-background-color).

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    updateUrl();
  });
  
  function updateUrl(){
    $('.currentUrl').text(location);
    var selector = "." + location.hash.substr(1);
    $(selector)
      .css("backgroundColor","#aa0000")
      .css("color", "#fff")
      .animate({
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          color: "#000",
        }, 1000 );
  }
  
  updateUrl();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="currentUrl"></div>
<a href="#asdfg">asdfg</a>
<a href="#qwert">qwert</a>
<a href="#zxcvb">zxcvb</a>
<div class="asdfg">Div with class asdfg</div>
<div class="qwert">Div with class qwert</div>
<div class="zxcvb">Div with class zxcvb</div>
```